# TypeError: pointplot() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This bit of code used to run without the error notification that follows the code. Any clues as to why this is happening here?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(16,5))

w = sns.pointplot(y='DelayTime',x='Weather2',data=df[['Weather2','DelayTime','Severity']],
                  hue = 'Severity'
                  ,ci=None  , 
               order= top_10_weather.index, #kind = 'point',
               height=4, aspect=2 , palette='nipy_spectral', ax= ax)

ax.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-', alpha=0.4)  

# w = sns.lineplot(x='Weather2', y='DelayTime' , data=df[['Weather2','DelayTime']] , hue_order= top_15_weather.index)

plt.xlabel("Weather conditions", fontdict = {'fontsize':12 , 'color':'MidnightBlue'} )
plt.xticks(fontsize=12 , rotation = 45)
plt.ylabel("Delay Times (in Hours)")

ax.set_title('Delay times for different Weather Conditions', fontdict = {'fontsize':16 , 'color':'MidnightBlue'}, pad=15)

fig.tight_layout()
```

**Error Statement Given**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23484\2440897390.py in <module>
      1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(16,5))
      2 
----> 3 w = sns.pointplot(y='DelayTime',x='Weather2',data=df[['Weather2','DelayTime','Severity']],
      4                   hue = 'Severity'
      5                   ,ci=None  ,

TypeError: pointplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'height'
```

The only reason i have for the code above to produce an error is a Anaconda Update as the code below worked before the update and it appears to be the same.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(16,5))

w = sns.pointplot(y='DelayTime',x='Weather2',data=df[['Weather2','DelayTime','Severity']],
                  hue = 'Severity'
                  ,ci=None  , 
               order= top_10_weather.index, #kind = 'point',
               height=4, aspect=2 , palette='nipy_spectral', ax= ax)

ax.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-', alpha=0.4)  

# w = sns.lineplot(x='Weather2', y='DelayTime' , data=df[['Weather2','DelayTime']] , hue_order= top_15_weather.index)

plt.xlabel("Weather conditions", fontdict = {'fontsize':12 , 'color':'MidnightBlue'} )
plt.xticks(fontsize=12 , rotation = 45)
plt.ylabel("Delay Times (in Hours)")

ax.set_title('Delay times for different Weather Conditions', fontdict = {'fontsize':16 , 'color':'MidnightBlue'}, pad=15)

fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: can you try `size` instead of `height` ?

Comment: Gives the same error for "size".

Comment: You need to remove both `height` and `aspect` as they aren't supported for axes-level functions.  In this case, that kind of changes needs to be made inside the call to `plt.subplots(...)`.  Probably in older seaborn versions these parameters were simply ignored without warning.  Seaborn can be a bit confusing, as subsequent versions do sometimes change the meaning of keywords.

Comment: Thanks, removing both 'height' and 'aspect' resolved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it worked before, but after reading the seaborn documentation ( [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) ) the parameter **height** doesn't exist when you use pointplot.